# Can I configure mysql Replication on port 13306 and normal database operation on 3306?

Tags: mysql

I know Mysql Replication works on 3306, but what I am trying to  understand is,

is there any way i can keep
a) 3306 for normal Mysql Operation and have 13306 for Replication purpose only ?

I have a requirment, where We need to setup mysql Repliation  over Dynamic IP which means our mysql server will be open to public, so we want to protect our database, and want to open minimum port which only for replication ( we will setup SSL replication)

b) if this is not possible , what other option do I have where we can only apply only changes from master to slave or master to master  ?

can this be done ?  thanks for sharing any lights or references on this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

MySQL replication normally works over the same port as any other MySQL connection, which is by default `3306`, as you correctly stated.

The standard ways to add protection:

- system level firewall, allowing traffic to `3306` only from specific host (replication peer)
- MySQL built-in authorization - e.g. `GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO 'repl'@'YOUR_TRUSTED_IP';`
- Add TLS for data-in-transit protection, as you mentioned.

If you choose to bind MySQL to a different port you will need to update your `CHANGE MASTER TO` configuration, have a look [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/change-master-to.html).

The only way I can think of, that would allow you to restrict the replication traffic itself, in any way, would be through the `GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE` command, where you could choose that only a particular user@host would have access.

Comment: Thanks, if i want to summarize  , Can I use both 3306 and 13306 at  same time ?  and  allow all Mysql Connection  via 3306 and only Replication via 13306 ?    
Thanks